# no match for operator== with 2D vector, enums and pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, enums, operator-overloading

So, here's my problem : I want to create a class than can be compared with == to inner enumerated values, according to its arguments. So here's what I tried:

```
class Type
{
public:
    enum T_values   {VALUE,
                     OTHERVALUE
                     };

    Type(T_values value) : m_value(value) {}
    bool operator==(T_values& value) {return (value == m_value);}

private:
    T_values m_value;
};

struct foo
{
    foo(Type TYPE) :  m_Ts(1, std::vector<Type*>(1, &TYPE)) {}
    std::vector<std::vector<Type*>> m_Ts;
    void bar(int, int);
};

void foo::bar(int i, int j)
{
    if(*m_Ts[i][j] == Type::VALUE)
    { cout<<"it works"; }
}

int main()
{
    Type TYPE(Type::VALUE);
    foo test(TYPE);
    test.bar(0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

And then, I have a beautifull and clear compilation error :

```
...\workspace\main.cpp|29|error: no match for 'operator==' in '*(&((foo*)this)->foo::m_Ts.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<Type*>, std::allocator<std::vector<Type*> > >(((std::vector<std::vector<Type*> >::size_type)i)))->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<Type*, std::allocator<Type*> >(((std::vector<Type*>::size_type)j)) == (Type::T_values)0u'|
```

And... I have no clue. Any ideas ?

Comment: You actually have more serious problems once you fix the compilation error, namely [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you will have a stray pointer in the vectors of vectors. The reason is that you pass the argument `TYPE` to the `foo` constructor *by value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this line:

```
bool operator==(T_values& value) {return (value == m_value);}
```

into this:

```
                    //  v-- no reference
bool operator==(T_values value) {return (value == m_value);}
```

You cannot take the literal `Type::VALUE` by reference because it is not an object.

Comment: "You cannot take the literal `Type::VALUE` by reference because it is not an object." That's why you take it by const reference :-)

Comment: Does it make a difference ? I guess a pointer to an enum type isn't realy smaller than the type itself..

Comment: There's no sense in using const or rvalue references here, no. Just pass it by value, that's my advice. I'd (generally) do the same for all primitive types, except in function templates where I'd not introduce an overload just to treat them differently.

Answer (score 1):

You also have a problem with this line.

```
foo(Type TYPE) :  m_Ts(1, std::vector<Type*>(1, &TYPE)) {}
```

you are storing the address of a temporary object. That address is invalid when the function returns.

Comment: Yeah, I've notecied that, but it's for the exemple. In the real code I have a vector2d filled with nullptr, and I add things in it by using new